# How to limit people with changeable IP from register in application?

Tags: security, web

I am working on web project which allows You to create Your own trial virtual system. But there is one problem. Unfortunately one person is creating a lot of that systems and we are paying money for each created system, so we want to limit it in some way. We thought about SMS code but this is a trouble for ordinary user. We banned his IP but he switched do a mobile one and that caused change of his IP. Do You have any ideas for introducing some security model to limit that type of behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to tie to something like an email domain name (allowing one trial per domain), phone/SMS code, or make people link a CC (validate the CC, but don't charge, or charge a few cents and refund just to validate). The whole issue is a spectrum, the more you lock down people from abusing it, the more inconvenient it is for the legitimate users, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank You for answer. Unfortunately a suspicious man uses temporary mail services and create new accounts in domains like gmail also, so banning domain names are difficult. Could You tell me what type of security is the least onerous for You?